# Flex 3 http fields cannot set encoding to utf-8

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am sending an email using HTTPService. I use UTF-8 in my app. When I send the email the ü is not correct.

I tried setting the service.headers to:

```
service.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' };
service.url = serviceRequest;
service.useProxy = false;
service.method = "POST";
var token:AsyncToken =service.send();
```

I have no other clues.

Hope someone has an answer,
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: The problem is probably in the server side code.  Setting email encodings correctly is far more complicated, than one would expect. Especially for the header fields.

Comment: _Any ideas how I can check this. I am using wireshark to check what is sent. I don't really have access to what the server is doing._

Comment: 1) Set up a suite of unit tests to verify that the form input is encoded correctly. 2) Set up a set of integration tests to verify that what's being sent is _actually_ what you intended to send. 3) Set up your own mail service (a simple servlet or php script should be enough) to verify that what's being received can be transformed into a correct email. 4) Use these tests to communicate your problem to whoever is running the server - if everything works on your end, and it is reproducible, the provider should be able to fix what's broken.